# Including word-generated A3-table with screenshot-pictures and Excel-generated diagramms in the cells

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a A3-size Sheet made with Word, some columns contain jpgs from screenshots and some excel-generated charts. When I created this table I wasn't aware that it will go into my latex-pdf file. I think it would not be good to shrink it, so I search a way to put this table somehow as a double page (left part of the table on a even page, right part on a odd page -- Can I make a header across the page break?)

One way I see is to create a whole new latex table including the images in the table grid (I hope this is possible ) and to make all format adjustments all over again.
Or I can input the pdf via pdfpages Package, which does not support to split A3 to two A4 and insert it.

**What would you think would be the best way to include the table?** Has anybody had the problem?
Thanks for your ideas in advance

Comment: I really recommend redoing that table in LaTeX. If possible redo the charts too. Images can indeed be included in tables simply. If you include the sheet as it is, it's likely to look very out of place. If you put an image of it up for us, perhaps we can make some suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: You mention JPEG screenshots. That's wrong in most of the cases. JPEG is used for photorealistic images, not for geometric ones. I assume that your screenshots show some kind of GUI or program interface. With GTK3 applications (and I guess on Mac, too) you can save the screenshots as vector graphics (e.g. in PDF format). The second choice is to save them as PNGs. Saving as JPEGs will show ugly artefacts on sharp edges (e.g. text).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on, what final quality you aim for. Here are three possibilities, best quality first.

If it's worth it, the best quality would be to redo the tables in LaTeX and maybe also to regenerate the graphs (e.g. using pgfplot). That yields the best quality, since the fonts match your document fonts and the graphics are created as scalable vector graphics and have a consistent look and equal line widths.

The next easiest solution would be to reuse the graphics but to redo the tables (or the other way round, depending on what looks better). This way you save a lot of time otherwise needed to create the graphics/tables.

The quickest but ugliest solution is to include your existing file. One half for the left and the other half for the right page.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with pgfplot, it's nice to know about it, but for the moment I think I follow you mid-quality-suggestion to redo the table but input the same graphics